# Como obter números realmente aleatórios com 'rand()' em C?

Tags: c, random, números-aleatórios

Pra um trabalho escolar, preciso criar um jogo, para qual preciso gerar um número aleatório para torná-lo justo. Em um dos casos, como vou postar abaixo, preciso designar um número aleatório entre 0 e 2 para modificar na string:

```
int NUM, AUX;
char PORTAS [0] = {'N', 'N', 'N'};

printf ("Entre com o número de participantes: ");
scanf ("%i", &NUM);

PART JOG [NUM];

for ( AUX = 0 ; AUX < NUM ; AUX++ ){
    ent_info (&JOG [AUX], AUX);
}

AUX = rand () %3;
PORTAS [AUX] = 'S';
```

O problema é que todas as vezes, AUX recebe o número 2 e preciso gerar outros dois números aleatórios além desse. Como posso contornar esse problema? Obrigado.

Comment: Coloque outras partes do código, principalmente onde está iniciando a semente randômica. O problema deve estar ali.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muito provavelmente não estás a inicializar a semente para a gerar os números pseudo-aleatórios. Como isto é apenas para um trabalho escolar a forma mais comum de gerar números aleatórios em C deverá ser suficiente.

Podes fazer algo assim:

```
(...)
srand(time(NULL)); //inicializar semente

int NUM, AUX;
char PORTAS [0] = {'N', 'N', 'N'};

printf ("Entre com o número de participantes: ");
scanf ("%i", &NUM);

PART JOG [NUM];

for ( AUX = 0 ; AUX < NUM ; AUX++ ){
    ent_info (&JOG [AUX], AUX);
}

AUX = rand () %3;  //Numero aleatório entre 0 e 2
PORTAS [AUX] = 'S';
```

Existem outras alternativas/algoritmos para a geração de números aleatórios. Se precisares de algo com "melhor" qualidade comparativamente com a solução da biblioteca stdlib, podes usar por exemplo o "Mersenne Twister". É bastante rápido e facilmente encontras uma implementação. Por exemplo [aqui](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/mtwist.html).

Para mais informação podes sempre consultar a página: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister